# How to redirect customer to cart page if they are login from checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer

When customer login on checkout page then redirect to cart page in magento2?
if they are login from others pages then redirect customer dashboard page.

Comment: Hie Jugal is there any update because i need same thing

Comment: yes! I created a module for this. it tested and working fine

Comment: great can you please share it.

Comment: No thanks dear no problem i will create :)

Comment: No problem i will provide free

Comment: @Akshay Thakkar!    see my answer!

Comment: thank you @Jugal Kishor

Answer (score 1):

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Redirect-to-Account-Dashboard-During-Checkout-Funnel-Login/td-p/74271

set
$response['redirectUrl'] = $this->url->getUrl('checkout/cart');

Comment: thank you for sharing its working.

Comment: Welcome! Enjoy!

Comment: @JugalKishor: I have also same kind of requirment like If customer is login from cart page it should redirect to Checkout page. any suggestions?

Comment: @BalwantSingh
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285118/magento-2-how-to-redirect-customer-for-checkout-after-login-when-cart-is-not-e