# Magento 2 - How to Redirect Customer for Checkout After Login when cart is not empty

Tags: magento2, customer-account, redirect

How to redirect customers to the checkout page after login when the cart is not empty for the customer?

**Loginpost\Redirect\etc\frontend\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
    <plugin name="loginpost_redirect_loginpostplugin" type="\LoginPost\Redirect\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

**Loginpost\Redirect\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Loginpost\Redirect\Plugin;

class LoginPostPlugin
{
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $result->setPath('/checkout');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting following error after adding this plugin to my project.

[image: plugin class does not exist error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a plugin for your requirement.

Create a di.xml file `/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` with below content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
    <plugin name="vendor_module_loginpostplugin" type="\Vendor\Module\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

Create LoginPostPlugin.php file `/Vendor/Module/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php` with below content.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class LoginPostPlugin
{
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $result->setPath('/checkout');
        return $result;
    }

}
```

> Reference from
>   [Magento 2 - Redirect customer to custom page after login](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134808/magento-2-redirect-customer-to-custom-page-after-login)

Comment: i'm new to magento and there is no directory named module inside vendor. instead of that can I create this plugin inside app/code directory ?

Comment: You need to create a new folder under `app/code/[vendor_name]/[module_name]`.
You can choose the Vendor and Module name as per your requirements.
For example, `/Sumit/CustomerLogin/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php`

Comment: I have don't this. But still not redirecting to checkout page after login. Are these two the only files inside this module ?

Comment: No, you need to create basic extension having Registration.php and module.xml file in etc folder. For example, /Sumit/CustomerLogin/etc/module.xml

Comment: I have added registration.php and module.xml inside etc folder to create a basic extension and  run `bin/magento setup:upgrade ` to add this plugin to the project. it's  run without error but i get a error  `1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Plugin class LoginPost\Redirect\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin doesn't exist`  , plugin file content and module.xml added in the question above. can you figure out what is went wrong with this.

Comment: Have you run the php bin/magento s:up and other deployment commands after adding the module?

Comment: You need to change your type in di.xml file from type="\LoginPost\Redirect\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin to type="\Loginpost\Redirect\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin

Comment: redirects work fine. but is there a possibility to check if cart is empty inside this plugin ?

Comment: Perfect, you can check it by current cart quote of the customer while login in the same plugin. If the customer having any product in the cart then redirect to the checkout.

Comment: Can I use this __construct function inside plugin to check if cart is not empty? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/269134/69209

Comment: Yes, you can use this in your plugin to check cart is empty or not.

Comment: this helped me to create the solution.  thanks lot for the support you have given.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create observer that fire event after customer login.

Create observer as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="<Your_packagename>\<Your_modulename>\Observer\RedirectCustommer" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create RedirectCustommer.php under "Your_packagename\Your_modulename\Observer"

```
<?php

namespace YourPackage\YourModle\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class RedirectCustommer implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     *@var\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
     */
    protected $quoteFactory;


    public function __construct(      
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,      
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory       
    )
    {       
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $landingurl =  $this->getRedirectUrl($customer->getId());
        if ($landingurl) {
                $resultRedirect = $this->responseFactory->create();
                $resultRedirect->setRedirect($landingurl)->sendResponse('200');
                exit();
        }
    }

    public function getRedirectUrl($customerId)
    {

        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId);
        if($quote->getId())
        {
            return $block->getUrl('checkout', ['_secure' => true]);
        }
        return false;

    }

    }
```

Comment: Amit, Plugin is the best method to override Magento's functionality instead of using observer.

Comment: Considered,But plugin is what used for change argument behavior and return value.

Comment: @Amitkumarsolanki  so what is the ideal way to do this ? using an observer or plugin. i'm using magento 2.1 for this project.

Comment: Both will be fine. but in some cases you should consider loading time for both.